# Django admin panel model in main page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have few admin models, how can I display one of the admin models in the admin panel main page so the fields of such model show without having to click on the model in admin panel homepage. Similar to the image below, a model field inside a box showing in the main admin page is what I need.

[image: admin panel main page]

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'admin.py' in your app directory

and add like this

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Book)
admin.site.register(Tag)
admin.site.register(Language)
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.. I already know and have that in place. I need the model fields to show in the admin panel main page, what you have mentioned shows the model name in admin panel and then once clicked it shows the fields. I need a way that shows the model fields in the admin panel without having to click on the model name.